# Publish npm package to a Gemfury registry with tag?

Tags: javascript, npm, publishing, gem-fury

I'm publishing an npm package to a private Gemfury registry through basic `npm login` / `npm publish` commands (as described in Gemgury's help section here: https://gemfury.com/help/npm-registry).

Simple publishing is working like a charm, but once I attempt to add in a version tag (`npm publish --tag beta` for example), I get a `Version already exists` error. That *version* does exist, but it does not with the specified tag.

If I bump the version to avoid the error and still pass in a tag, the package (at the new version) is successfully publised, but there is nothing (within Gemfury) that indicates a tag is present at all.

Does Gemfury support npm package version tags (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-tags)? I can't find any Gemfury documentation that suggests one way or another, but it seems like something pretty simple for a private npm registry to be able to handle.

Is there another way to get around this? I want what tags have to offer, but I don't necessarily need to follow that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of Gemfury, but after doing some experiments I think it considers the "version" element in "package.json" file.
I don't think it considers the git tag.

Hope this helps